# Angularjs responsive directive live updating issue (possibly due to ng-repeating the directive)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, responsive-design, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am creating a post feed by ng-repeating JSON files from the cloud. I tried to make the posts responsive by using angular directives that update the template url with the screen size.

**The problem is** that only the last post in the ng-repeat responds and changes templates (with or without the reverse filter) when I resize the page. The other posts just remain the template that it was when originally loaded.

Here's the ng-repeat in the page

```
<div ng-show="post_loaded" ng-repeat="post in posts | reverse | filter:searchText ">
    <feed-post>
    </feed-post>
</div>
```

Here's the directive javascript file

```
app.directive('feedPost', function ($window) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div ng-include="templateUrl"></div>',
    link: function(scope) {

        $window.onresize = function() {
            changeTemplate();
            scope.$apply();
        };
        changeTemplate();

        function changeTemplate() {
            var screenWidth = $window.innerWidth;
            if (screenWidth < 768) {
                scope.templateUrl = 'directives/post_mobile.html';
            } else if (screenWidth >= 768) {
                scope.templateUrl = 'directives/post_desktop.html';
            }
        }
    }
};});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you re-assigning the `.onresize` in each directive and it stays effective only for the last linked directive.

I'd suggest to use it in a more angular way. You don't actually need a custom directive

In the controller that manages list of posts add reference to `$window` in `$scope`

```
$scope.window = $window;
```

Then in template make use of it

```
<div ng-include="directives/post_mobile.html" ng-if="window.innerWidth < 768"></div>
<div ng-include="directives/post_desktop.html" ng-if="window.innerWidth >= 768"></div>
```

To avoid extra wrappers for posts feed you might want to use [`ng-repeat-start`, `ng-repeat-end` directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#special-repeat-start-and-end-points)

Answer (score 0):

this is a directive i wrote based on bootstrap sizes and ngIf directive :

```
mainApp.directive("responsive", function($window, $animate) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        transclude: 'element',
        terminal: true,
        link: function($scope, $element, $attr, ctrl, $transclude) {
            //var val = $attr["responsive"];
            var block, childScope;

            $scope.$watch(function(){ return $window.innerWidth; }, function (width) {

                if (width < 768) {
                    var s = "xs";
                } else if (width < 992) {
                    var s = "sm";
                } else if (width < 1200) {
                    var s = "md";
                } else {
                    var s = "lg";
                }
                console.log("responsive ok?", $attr.responsive == s);


              if ($attr.responsive == s) {
                if (!childScope) {
                  $transclude(function(clone, newScope) {
                    childScope = newScope;
                    clone[clone.length++] = document.createComment(' end responsive: ' + $attr.responsive + ' ');
                    block = {
                      clone: clone
                    };
                    $animate.enter(clone, $element.parent(), $element);
                  });
                }
              } else {
                if (childScope) {
                  childScope.$destroy();
                  childScope = null;
                }
                if (block) {
                    block.clone.remove();
                    block.clone = null;
                    block = null;
                }
              }
            });


        }
    };
});
```